# What should I use after 'detected': 'me steal', 'me to steal', or 'my stealing'?

Tags: word-choice, tense, gerunds, infinitives

Which of these sentences are correct:

> Sensors detected me steal something.
>
> Sensors detected me to steal something.
>
> Sensors detected my stealing something.

The situation is in the mall when you're trying to leave the building and suddenly the sensors triggered with a loud voice

Answer (score 4):

None of the above. The more natural way to say it would be:

> Sensors detected me stealing something.